# In BPMN2, How to handle user task data verification or re-entry task?

Tags: jbpm, activiti, bpmn, business-process-management

Something like this

[image]

SomeCheck may involve user action

Is this possible in bpmn2 ?

I'm new to process engine, is there any other way to handle these situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create process like this:
[image]

Where the user task will have some output like this:
[image]

And the second gateway will validate the output of previous user task:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution works in the following way

1. Actor fills in data
2. Actor completes task
3. Gateway evaluates condition
4. based on the condition new task is created.

I would say more convenient is
 1. Actor fills in data
 2. Actor completes task - the exception (check has failed) is immediately fired and user task is not completed. Actor has the possibility to fix the input.

**How to:**
Add listener to the user task and which will throw an exception in the case of check failure.
http://www.flowable.org/docs/userguide-5.22.0/index.html#taskListeners

Comment: The check is not immediately fired, because this check may contain service task to autocheck and user task to ensure the result is correct.So , I have to complete the fill data step instead of fail.

Comment: Makes sense. So you can model it.

Comment: Only problem with Martin's approach is that it is difficult to feedback to the user the reason for the failure other than perhaps a popup message saying something like "You can't request you tax documents without a tad id". Sure, it works, but it's kinda 90's.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly while the above works, it is really bad practise as it will skew your process tracking and rework data. And, it's just plain ugly, especially in today's responsive UI world.
You should validate fields and form field combinations prior to moving on in the process. 
Obviously, the out of box Activiti Community UI doesn't support this, but then the version 5 UI is very dated (more than 4 years old).

I strongly recommend a more robust UI layer (such as Brazos).
Greg

Comment: Yes, I can do most checks in web ui, but still, not all checks can be done in web ui.The check will involve automatic service task and manual user task to confirm the input data is valid.